# Is there any equivalent of Oracle's XMLQUERY in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to find equivalent of XMLQuery in PostgreSQL.

Following results I got from Oracle's [LiveSql](https://livesql.oracle.com/). Please suggest how to get same results on PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE TABLE person_data (
person_id   NUMBER(3),
person_data XMLTYPE);

INSERT INTO person_data
(person_id, person_data)
VALUES
(1, XMLTYPE('<PDRecord>
     <PDName>Daniel Morgan</PDName>
     <PDDOB>12/1/1951</PDDOB>
     <PDEmail>damorgan@u.washington.edu</PDEmail>
 </PDRecord>')
);

INSERT INTO person_data
(person_id, person_data)
VALUES
(2, XMLTYPE('<PDRecord>
     <PDName>Taner Poder</PDName>
     <PDDOB>5/17/1949</PDDOB>
     <PDEmail>damorgan@u.washington.edu</PDEmail>
   </PDRecord>')
);

SELECT person_id,
XMLQuery('for $i in /PDRecord
 return $i/PDName'
PASSING BY VALUE person_data
RETURNING CONTENT) XMLData
FROM person_data;
```

Output:

```
 PERSON_ID  XMLDATA

 1      <PDName>Daniel Morgan</PDName>
 2      <PDName>Taner Poder</PDName>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `xpath()` function:

```
select pd.person_id, 
       (xpath('/PDRecord/PDName', pd.person_data))[1]
from person_data pd;
```

This returns

```
person_id | xpath                         
----------+-------------------------------
        1 | <PDName>Daniel Morgan</PDName>
        2 | <PDName>Taner Poder</PDName>
```

`xpath()` returns an array of matches. `[1]` then picks the first element of that array.

If you want the raw content of the tag, then xmltable() is more suitable as it's also easier to add more columns:

```
select pd.person_id, 
       x.*
from person_data pd
  cross join xmltable('/PDRecord' passing pd.person_data
                      columns name text path 'PDName', 
                              email text path 'PDEmail')  as x
```

This returns:

```
person_id | name          | email                    
----------+---------------+--------------------------
        1 | Daniel Morgan | damorgan@u.washington.edu
        2 | Taner Poder   | damorgan@u.washington.edu
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9eace732300305ecc1146cdc1bf9d07b)